# Java doesn't understand the logic of this code

Tags: java

I have a code from a tutorial for a Java Breakout Game. The part of the code is the Brickmap. The problem is i don't really understand the logic behind this code and i will not just copy the code.

I just know that  creat a variable map with an array. After that i put the two variable "row" and "col" in this array. The Problem is that i dont understand the "map.lenght".

```
import java.awt.*;

public class BrickMap {
   int map[][];
   int brickHeight;
   int brickWigth;


public BrickMap(int row, int col){
    map= new int [row][col];
    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++){
            map[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

    brickWigth = 640/col;
    brickHeight = 170/row;

}

public void draw(Graphics2D g){
    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {

            if(map[i][j] > 0){
                g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                g.fillRect(j *brickWigth + 80, i *brickHeight + 50 , brickWigth, brickHeight);

                g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
                g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                g.drawRect(j *brickWigth + 80, i *brickHeight + 50 , brickWigth, brickHeight);

            }
        }
    }


}

public void setBrickValue(int value, int row, int col){
    map[row][col] = value;



}






}
```

Comment: `map[0].length` means that the first line's or row's lenght in array. Because your lines can be different length in two dimension array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is a two-dimensional array. `map.length` specifies the length of the first dimension defined by `row`. `map[0].length` in turn specifies the length of the first array of the second dimension.

Comment: Thank you it has helped a lot

Comment: and what is the meaning of `map[i][j] = 1;`?

Comment: As `map` is an array of arrays, it assigns a value at the (inner) array location specified by `i` and `j`. `i` defines the outer array index and `j` the inner array index.

Answer (score 1):

`map.length` returns the number of elements in the array.

`map[0].length` returns the number of elements in the first array within the map array (which is two-dimensional).